How to create Tree map that would show certain category that the selected product is in
I am creating a dashboard in Power BI and want to build a visual (specifically a tree map) that shows how a selected product is performing within its subcategory. The idea is that when a user selects a product via a slicer, the visual should extract the subcategory of the chosen product and filter the tree map accordingly to show performance within that subcategory.
I attempted to write a DAX measure to achieve this behavior, but the solution doesn't seem to work. I also blocked interactions between the slicer and the tree map visual to prevent other issues, but I still don't get the desired outcome.
Any advice on how to approach this?
So I tried to write a code with a help from Chat GPT. We created 2 measures:
SelectedSubCategories = 
VAR SelectedProduct = SELECTEDVALUE(FactSales[Product]) 
RETURN 
IF (
    ISBLANK(SelectedProduct),
    BLANK(), -- Jeśli nie wybrano żadnego produktu, zwróć BLANK
    CONCATENATEX(
        VALUES(FactSales[Sub_Category]), 
        FactSales[Sub_Category], 
        ", "
    )
)

This one is supposed to extract the subcategories of the selected product
ShowProductsInSameSubCategory = 
IF(
    [SelectedSubCategories] = MAX(FactSales[Sub_Category]),
    1,
    0
)

And this one is supposed to be used as a filter on the treemap to show only subcategories that are the same as the selected product. From what I have explored, first code is extracting the subcategories correctly but the second one is not filtering correctly. How to solve this issue?
